# Bijection function from Vitali set to real numbers

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to construct a bijection function from vitali set to the real number. As you may know vitali set has been defined as following.
Define an equivalence relation on $\\R$ by $$x\sim y\iff x-y\in{\\Q}.$$ by choosing exactly one element from each class we will get a vitali set.  So, define a function from $V$ to $\\R$ as following by

$f(v)=[x]$ where $\\R=\bigcup_{x\in{\\R}}[x]$. It is clear injective and we can define another injective function from $\bigcup_{x\in{\\R}}[x]$ to $V.$Thus, byCantor-Schroder-Bernstein, we will have a bijective function from $V$ to $\\R.$

Is this correct? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you write $R = \bigcup_{x \in R} [x]$.

Comment: Neither of your functions is actually a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $V$ or vice versa as you've written them here.

Comment: Also, note that you may not _have_ a Vitali set if the Axiom of Choice exists, and the CSB theorem you're using doesn't depend on AC, so if you can't identify where in this 'proof' AC is used, odds are good it's not a proof.

Comment: @xyzzyz  These are  equivalence classes from the relation we define on $\\R$

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, Do you have any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

$V\subseteq \mathbb R,$ so clearly we have an injective map one way, so the nontrivial part is to find an injective map $\mathbb R\to V.$ However, constructing explicit maps is rarely the way to go... it's usually much more expedient to rely on a few fundamental theorems about cardinality.

First, notice that we have an explicit bijection between $V\times \mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ given by $(v,q)\to v+q.$ In cardinal arithmetic terms, this means $$ |V|\cdot |\mathbb Q| = |\mathbb R|.$$ So if we have at our disposal the basic rules of cardinal arithmetic, i.e. that $\lambda \cdot \kappa = \max(\lambda,\kappa),$ then we immediately get $|V|=|\mathbb R|.$ (There are some niceties involving axiom of choice here - in fact this cardinality argument would be dead in the water without it - but we already need a good amount of choice to construct the Vitali set, so it's safe to say we can assume it freely.)

The way this cardinal arithmetic statement is usually proved (adapted and slightly simplified for this special case) is as follows: First use AC to put $V$ and $\mathbb Q$ into one-to-one correspondence with the least ordinals they can be put into one-to-one correspondence with (i.e. their cardinals). Call $|V|=\kappa$ and of course $|\mathbb Q| = \omega.$

Then the problem of showing there is an injective function $V\times \mathbb Q\to V$ is reduced to showing there is an injective function $\kappa\times\omega\to \kappa.$ To see this, consider the order type of the dictionary well-ordering on $\kappa\times\omega.$ Assume for induction that the statement is true for all infinite cardinals less than $\kappa$ (there is the standard "diagonal path" construction for the base case $\omega\times \omega\to \omega$). Then for any $\langle\alpha,n\rangle \in \kappa\times \omega,$ with $\alpha$ infinite, we have an injection $\alpha\times \omega\to \alpha$ so that $|\alpha\times \omega |\le |\alpha| < \kappa.$ This guarantees that since the initial segment less than $\langle \alpha,n\rangle$ is a subset of $\alpha \times \omega,$ it has order type less than $\kappa.$ Thus the order type of $\kappa\times \omega$ is $\le \kappa,$ and the well ordering gives an injective function $\kappa\times\omega\to \kappa.$

Comment: it helps a lot. Thank you so much

Comment: I got confused again because this function$V\times \mathbb Q\to V$ is projection map which is not injective at all. could you please clarify this point to me

Comment: @gb2017 why do you think it is a projection map?

Comment: @gb2017 I will just clarify what it is. Any well ordered set is isomorphic to some unique ordinal called its order type. This isomorphism provides a one to one correspondence between it and an ordinal. What the last paragraph shows is that the dictionary order on $\kappa \times \omega$ has order type less than or equal to $\kappa,$ which means there’s an isomorphism onto an initial segment of $\kappa,$ which is an injective function into $\kappa.$ (And actually this must be onto as well, by the easier cardinality argument in the other direction.)

Comment: @gb2017 I’ll add that this argument is just an adaptation of one standard proof for arbitrary cardinalities. (I know of another that uses Zorn’s lemma instead of well ordering, but I don’t think it’s any simpler.) It’s quite possible there’s an easier proof that only works for the reals that I’m not thinking of. For instance if you only want to show that $V$ is uncountable, there’s an easy proof without needing cardinal arithmetic.